# Ensure KClass of class that implements interface

Tags: kotlin, generics, jvm, covariance

I have a custom converter annotation like:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class CustomConverter(val converter: KClass<*>)
```

And I have an interface:

```
interface FooConverter<T> {
    fun from(str: String): T?
    fun to(value: T): String
}
```

And I have a class implementing this interface:

```
class BarConverter : FooConverter<Int> {
   // Implementation
}
```

And I use the annotation like:

```
class MyDTO {
    @CustomConverter(BarConverter::class)
    var myProp: Int? = null
}
```

Is there a way to ensure the `KClass` on the annotation has a class that implements the `FooConverter<T>` interface?

I have tried:

```
annotation class CustomConverter(val converter: KClass<FooConverter<*>>)

annotation class CustomConverter(val converter: KClass<FooConverter<Any>>)
```

but it doesn't work. The compiler complains.

Thanks!

Comment: `val converter: KClass<out FooConverter<*>>` ? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Comment: That is because generics are invariant by default. To understand invariance, covariance, and contravariance in generics better checkout this article: https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47

Comment: Ahhhh... I knew it was something about the variance... But thought it was something about my interface... And I couldn't change because I have `T` in and out, of course...
Didn't that about generics... It worked. If you guys want to make an answer out of it I would gladly check as the right one. Thanks!